Help with using "infinitesimal Riemann sums" to arrive at the formula for arclength
I am trying to arrive at the formula for arclength using infinitesimals. So far, I have a definition which says:
$\displaystyle \mathrm{Re}\sum_{k=0}^{\omega}f(x_k)\Delta x:=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$
where $\displaystyle \mathrm{Re}$ is my real-part function (my framework isn't identical to regular non-standard analysis, so I have slightly different notation). In this case, $\omega$ is a multiplicative inverse to some infinitesimal and $x_k$ and $\Delta x$ are defined in the classic Riemann sum fashion.
I have been able to succesfully abuse this definition for a few derivations so far, including formulas for rotation around different axes. However, I can't quite get it to work when trying to derive the formula for arclength. I will sketch out my attempt below:
Pick a point $(x_k, f(x_k))$, and make an infinitesimal increment $\Delta x$, such that you arrive at the point $(x_k+\Delta x, f(x_k+\Delta x))$. Using this, we can approximate the length of the curve over the subinterval $[x_k, x_k+\Delta x]$ as the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle:
$S_{sub}\approx\sqrt{(\Delta f(x_k))^2+(\Delta x)^2}$
If we repeat this process infinitely many times, that is we calculate:
$\displaystyle S_{tot}\approx\sum_{a}^{b}S_{sub}=\sum_{k=0}^{\omega}\sqrt{1+(\frac{\Delta f(x_k)}{\Delta x})^2}\Delta x$
We should arrive at a length which is infinitesimally close to the actual arclength. Then, all we have to do is apply the real part function:
$\displaystyle S_{tot}=\mathrm{Re}\sum_{k=0}^{\omega}\sqrt{1+(\frac{\Delta f(x_k)}{\Delta x})^2}\Delta x$
I am very tempted to just rewrite this in terms of the integral, but I not sure how to motivate that here. In previous derivations, it has been easy because I have always arrived at expressions where you can easily match terms with the definition, for example:
$\displaystyle \mathrm{Re}\sum_{k=0}^{\omega}2\pi x_kf(x_k)\Delta x=2\pi\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)\mathrm{d}x$
Here, rewriting it as an integral isn't a problem because you can find a function $g$ such that $g(x_k)=2\pi x_kf(x_k)$ and then apply the definition to :
$\displaystyle \mathrm{Re}\sum_{k=0}^{\omega}g(x_k)\Delta x$
You may try to do something similar here, for example by letting $\displaystyle g(x_k)=\sqrt{1+\frac{\Delta f(x_k)}{\Delta x}}$, but then, using the definition right of the bat, you would get $\Delta f/\Delta x$ under the root sign instead of $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}x$.
I hope my question is clear. Basically, I want a way to use the definition of the integral as written above to arrive at the formula for arclength. I apologize for any language mistakes, English is not my native language.

You shouldn't use "Re" for your version of standard part, because Re is typically used for the real part of a complex number.  This could be confusing.

@MikhailKatz, I agree that it could cause confusion, but in the scope of my project I think it's fine (where I live you have to write a "term paper" to graduate form high school.)
I didn't want to use "$\mathrm{std}$", because the numers I have "created" are different from hyperreals in terms of sophistication and construction. What do you think I should use? Do you think I should just opt for "$\mathrm{std}$" anyway?

Take $\omega=\frac{1}{dx}$ (without losing generality we can assume so. The integral doesn't depends on how would you "divide" an interval).  Let $x_i=a+i(b-a-2\delta)dx+\delta$ where $\delta$ is some sufficiently small infinitesimal (I chose such $x's$ because of this: Divide interval $(a,b)$ into $\omega$ pieces $P_1=(a,a+dx), P_2=[a+dx,a+2dx),...,P_{\omega-1}=[b-2dx,b-dx), P_\omega=[b-dx,b)$. Then for any $1\le i\le \omega$ we have $x_i\in P_i$) We got:
$\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}\sqrt{1+(\frac{f(x_i+dx)-f(x_i)}{dx})^2}dx=dx\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}\sqrt{1+(\frac{f(x_i+dx)-f(x_i)}{dx})^2}$.
One can prove that  $\sqrt{1+(\frac{f(x_i+dx)-f(x_i)}{dx})^2}\approx \sqrt{1+f'(x_i)^2}$ easily. Therefore there is some infintiesimal $\varepsilon$ that $\sqrt{1+(\frac{f(x_i+dx)-f(x_i)}{dx})^2}= \sqrt{1+f'(x_i)^2}+\varepsilon$. This means that:
$dx\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}\sqrt{1+(\frac{f(x_i+dx)-f(x_i)}{dx})^2}=dx\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}(\sqrt{1+f'(x_i)^2}+\varepsilon)=^{(*)}dx\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}\sqrt{1+f'(x_i)^2}+dx\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}\varepsilon=dx\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}\sqrt{1+f'(x_i)^2}+dx\cdot \omega \varepsilon=dx\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}\sqrt{1+f'(x_i)^2}+\varepsilon\approx dx\sum_{1\le i\le \omega}\sqrt{1+f'(x_i)^2}=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$
$^{(*)}$ In case of this equality we have to use this fact: Let $a,b,c$ be real 1-ary functions. Let $P$ be relation that defines natural numbers (in real numbers). Let $f(n),g(n),h(n)$ denotes functions that has a property $\forall n\, P(n)\to f(n)=\sum_{1\le i\le n} a(n)$, $\forall n\, P(n)\to g(n)=\sum_{1\le i\le n} b(n)$, $\forall n\, P(n)\to h(n)=\sum_{1\le i\le n} a(n)+b(n)$.  Also suppose we have  additional propertie  that $\forall n\, P(n)\to c(n)=a(n)+b(n)$. Then by transfer principle, $\forall n\, P(n)\to h(n)=f(n)+g(n)$. In my proof I assume some additional stuff (formally $dx$ doesn't has to be a constant. We have to make sure that all of the stuff should converge to sum finite value etc. But if we know it then indeed the conclusion is valid). Basically if we can prove that  $\sqrt{1+f'(x)²}+r$ for any sufficiently small $r$  is integrable on the interval then indeed this sum will be infinitely close to the integral as it basically is sum with one particular chosen partition of the interval.
